# Selenium DoubleClick WebElement causing Error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using the code below to stimulate a double mouse click on a button, however, I am getting a compile error which is pointing towards the actions but I don't no how to fix it.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"))).build().perform();
    logger1.info("Logout Successful");

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class testNG.RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:44)
    at testNG.RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest.<init>(RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest.java:25)
    ... 26 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to fire the doubleclick event using javascript.
This is how I do for triggering the click event from selenium, I guess that you can adapt it for triggering a  doubleclick

```
    public static void phantomClick (WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
        final String script = "function ghostclick(el){var ev = document.createEvent(\"MouseEvent\");ev.initMouseEvent(\"click\",true ,true,window,null,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);el.dispatchEvent(ev);} return ghostclick(arguments[0])";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, element);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,

I've got this working now: Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"))).build().perform();
    logger1.info("Logout Successful");

Comment: Unsure how to confirm that it has done a double click though? is there anyway to confirm it has doubled clicked?

Comment: It does a single click for me.

Answer (score 0):

A [`TestNGException`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNGException.html) isn't a compile error. It is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) thrown by TestNG. In this case TestNG threw the exception because it could not "instantiate class testNG.RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest".

Here is the reason why:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:44)
    at testNG.RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest.<init>(RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest.java:25)
```

This means that when initializing/constructing an instance of `RAD3398LogoutTwiceTest` that a constructor for [`Actions`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) was invoked which then threw a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) on line 44.

If you take a look at [Actions.java:44](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d4451336fd08877f6348271d0a896ec13630f709/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java#L44) you'll see `this.mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();`. i.e. The initialization failed because `driver` is `null`.

Make sure that any statements like `new Actions(driver);` occur after `driver` is initialized or your test class will fail to initialize and TestNG will throw an exception.

Once you fix this issue your statement to double-click should execute.

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative workaround Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004164/perform-doubleclick-on-element-that-have-that/35004330)

Simplified to this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('map_container').dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick'));");
```